# Detect changes of VM parameters

Tags: monitoring, datacenter

We run VMs in remote data centers. We are responsible for the VM, but not for the hypervisor.

We want to detect changes in the resources of the VM.

Example:

1. VM has 10GByte memory - everything is fine
2. Remote data center changes its setting, we only get 7 GByte and forgets to inform us.
3. Customer calls us: Our service is slow
4. Since the customer is responsible for the remote data center, I want to detect since when we have less resources.

I could solve this with some scripts, but I would like to reuse an existing tool.

How to track this?

Comment: Do you have any monitoring applications that you use?

Comment: @Citizen we have a simple solution which calls checks like nagios. But up to now we have no tool to track data like physical memory of VMs.

Comment: Who is responsible for the hypervisor?  The customer as cited in #4?  Or some other vendor?  Couldn't you ask whoever is responsible for the hypervisor to include you in the Change Management of the VMs?

Comment: Yes, the customer is responsible for the hypervisor. I am not very familiar with big data centers. How does "include you in the Change Management of the VMs" look like?